# Lions and Zebras on a Chess Board

Tags: mathematics, strategy, game, checkerboard, pursuit-evasion

The black knight is our lion chasing 8 white bishop zebras which can't capture. Can the zebras evade the lion forever, if team zebra positions all the pieces and has the first turn?

Rules:

- The game is played on a standard 8x8 chess board
- Zebras move like bishops but can't capture
- Lions move like knights and only need to capture one zebra to win
- The Zebra team will always play their best game to avoid capture
- Zebras get to position all pieces to their advantage
- Zebras can choose to first move if they desire
- Each side moves a single piece per turn

Question:
If there are 8 zebras and only 1 lion, can the lion win?

If you lion can win how does it do so? If the zebras always win (escape) where on the board do they and the lion start and what is their strategy?

*While the answers so far are a good start they still don't completely answer the question. I might offer a bounty on this question and I would definitely award it to anyone who can prove that the Lion can always win. (if that is the case)*

Comment: Do all the zebra's move at once or do they move one after the other? Also I think it really depends on the situation of the bord

Comment: That is the essence of the question. Can the zebras find a starting position and strategy that ensures victory.

Comment: Tougher variant: what's the minimum number of zebras to ensure the lion can get a meal.

Comment: Is this a standard 8x8 chess board?

Comment: Uhh.. obviously, the zebras just lie down and escape the lions using the camouflage of the black and white chess board. Too easy.

Comment: @IanMacDonald , this is a cheese board, so when the Mouse eats it up, the Zebras will have no camouflage.

Comment: It may be possible to search all situations with an efficient computer algorithm. There are only so many unique situations, considering various different situations that are symmetric in one way or the other.

Comment: No one else interested in this question? ='(

Comment: Did you cook up the problem yourself?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty: I didn't post the question.

Comment: @justhalf Ya I meant to ask Bob

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty Yeah I did. I'm still unsure what the solution is.

Comment: Can someone maybe write a computer program to check some of the solutions below? Or to check all possible states, for that matter, as mentioned by @ghosts_in_the_code?

Comment: @Bob I just asked cause maybe you knew the answer and were testing us. Well that's  not the case it seems.

Comment: Has a correct answer at *long* last been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 12):

I will place the Zebras as follows :

> [image]

Then whenever the knight attacks any piece, I will move it to its adjacent diagonal so that it is contained within these boxes :

> [image]

Now, the knight cannot fork two pieces inside same box(as they are of opposite colour). Also knight cannot fork two pieces from two boxes as they are quite apart...(4 places between them). So I will just have to make sure that the knight does not capture me in next move and I am safe...

Note that if the knight attacks from c3(only time when I will have to leave box) or such similar square I will diagonally move to the opposite box. From c3 he will have to go to e2 then g3 then f1 then e3 then his attacks will end (any other move will also mean end of attack). Then I will take back my piece to where it was. So initial condition.

Comment: But the knight can attack both the current position of the zebra and the one it would move to.

Comment: Aren't the zebras supposed to stay on the white squares? From the question: "... 8 white bishop zebras ...".

Comment: @Lawrence white in piece colour, not square.  If it were square then you should be much more confused at the reference to black knight.

Comment: @EagleV_Attnam: Condition covered starting from "Note that".

Comment: @LeppyR64 Yes, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: In the section detailing c3 how do you guarantee that the spot you are moving your zebra to doesn't contain a zebra already?    If you can not guarantee this; have you considered the followup of d5 rather than e2?(blocking the return path of the zebra).

Comment: Lion move sequence with initial zebras in the positions given in answer (zebras moves omitted):  B4,A6,C7,B5,D6,F7,H6,F5,G3,E2,C3.  Zebra move B1-H7 blocked by Zebra at H7.

Comment: @Taemyr , your first comment doesn't pose much problem to me but your second comment has stumped me...I can't answer that...Do you have any further ideas to improve my answer ?

Comment: The second comment is an example to show that the first comment is a potential concern.  The problem is that it might not always be possible to move the zebra diagonally to the other corner.

Comment: it needn't reach the opposite box, if that square is occupied.  if H7 is already occupied, G6 suffices, as the knight would need to make at least one intervening move where no bishops are attacked to reach any square (F8, F4, H4) where the bishop at G6 is forked.  on that one intervening move G6 moves back to its home box, and normalcy is restored.

Comment: It is possible to go from C3 to attack a different box, say the lower right by moving to F3, without any non-attacking moves, but one of those attacks would be on either G6 (allowing it to move "home" right then) or H7 (which moves to G8, which then cannot be forked against G6 without a non-attacking intervening move, leaving you no worse off than before.

Comment: @Rubio: Looks good so far. If you can generalize that (or prove that it doesn't lose generalization) I think we might have a complete answer. Is it always the case that after knight moves to C3 (or the equivalent in any sequence of moves leading to this predicament), there are no two bishops at G1 and G2 (because in that case knight to E2 --attacking G1-- then F4 would fork G2 and G6)? Also, forking isn't the only way to capture, if a bishop is stuck (see JonTheMon's answer) and then attacked it is also a win for lion.

Comment: Oh my God! So, many things have happened since I last logged in. Sorry everyone...I had realised that my answer wasn't correct long ago. The only reason I didn't delete it is because it might inspire someone and produce an awesome solution. As for me, I am stuck in purgatorio so I can't contribute anything. However if anyone feels that my answer is misleading I will gladly delete it.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty: Definitely this answer is not misleading, as it can help other people to complete it, as you thought. But this question hasn't really received much attention, so I guess the answer for this question won't be improved yet =/

Comment: If lion can force a situation where it arrives at C3 with zebras at B1, B2, G1, G2, and H7, it can catch a zebra.  If Zebra to A2 or E4, lion wins instantly.  If Zebra to C2 or F5, lion goes to D1 (Zebra at B2 must move), then E3, forking G2 and C2/F5.  If Zebra to D3 or G6, Lion moves to E2 (Zebra at G1 must move), then F4, forking G2 and D3/G6.  Can you show that the lion can't force that situation?

Answer (score 9):

*Note*: The following full answer expands on the previous partial answer, which has been retained below.

## Full answer

To analyze all the possible states, the algorithm Ken Thompson described in his 1986 paper [*Retrograde Analysis of Certain Endgames*](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~rsc/thompson86endgame.pdf), which was used to develop some of the earliest chess endgame tablebases, was adapted for this question. His method starts at known winning positions and moves backward in time ("unmoves") to predecessor positions. Those positions are analyzed and the ones that always lead to defeat are added to the list of losing positions. Then new predecessor positions of the losing positions are analyzed. This continues until there are no new predecessors.

At the end of the analysis, either all possible positions have been added to the list of losing positions and a win is guaranteed with optimal play, or there is a subset of non-losing positions that can be leveraged to defend against a win.

Analysis of Lions and Zebras on a Chess Board leads to the conclusion that...

> ### In the jungle, the mighty jungle, the lion eats tonight...
>
> An optimal lion wins from every possible game position. Against optimal zebras each, the lion slightly improves with each move until his opponents run out of defenses. This takes 16 moves at most.
>
> [image: Chess board with black knight at b2 and white bishops at a1, a2, a7, a8, h1, h2, h7, and h8] *Lion eats in 16*
>
> This is a typical best-case setup for the zebras. They are arrayed in the corners and the lion lacks any immediate threatening moves. But even if the zebras could dictate the lion's first move, it would offer them no advantage. All the lion's initial moves lead to a captured zebra in 16 moves.
>
> Since the state space is too large to present a full analysis for the tens of billions of positions, the following analysis has been limited to this position. Further, it only looks at lines where the lion chooses **Nd1** as his first move. It produces a number interesting lines that demonstrate the strategies without having an unmanageable number of variations.
>
> Interestingly, in responding to **Nd1**, despite a plethora of options, the zebras only have two optimal replies: **Bab8** and **Bab1**. Anything else results in earlier capture.
>
> Analysis of the lines starting at this position are given in PGN format. Given the non-standard rules of the game, not all PGN viewers can handle them. But, as of this writing, the [PGN viewer on chess.com](https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor) works. (Choose *Load PGN* and paste in the PGN.). Zebra moves are annotated for only optimal move: '!'; suboptimal move: '?'; or highly suboptimal move: '??'.
>
> #### 1... Nd1 2. Bab8
>
> In moves 3 to 11, the zebras maintain their defensive posture by occupying the corners. But they only have one optimal move at each turn. On move 12, the zebras finally two options *Bab6* or *Bab2*, but either one forces the abandoment of the corners. Either way, the lion continues with b4, then c2, and on move 14 the a1 zebra then has four choices: b2, c3, e5, or f6. The lion continues to e3 and then no matter which of the eight combinations of moves the zebras chose on 12 and 14, the lion forks them on move 15.
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/Bn5B/B6B b - - 0 1"]
> [SetUp "1"] 1... Nd1 2. Bab8 Nf2 3. Bhg2! Ng4 4. Bg1! Nf6 5. Bhb1! Nd5 6. Bh7! Nb6 7. Bab7! Nd7 8. Bba7! Nf8 9. Bhg8! Ng6 10. Bhg7! Ne7 11. Bh7! Nc6 12. Bab6 Nb4 13. Bf7 Nc2 14. Bab2 Ne3 15. Bh1 Nc4 16. Ba1 Nxb6
>
> #### 1... Nd1 2. Bab1
>
> The lion leaves the zebras with only a single optimal choice on moves 3 to 10. Unlike the *Bab8* line, this line requires early abandonment of the corners. The zebras are finally afforded a choice on move 11, either Bc8 or Be8. But the table is already set and Nf7 forces Bhb2. The lion then threatens one zebra after another until he finally captures the a1 zebra trapped on move 12.
>
> The amazing thing about this line is that if the zebras play optimally the lion could play blind. In optimal play, the lion can use these same moves starting at move 2 and he will always capture the zebra on a1 on move 16.
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/Bn5B/B6B b - - 0 1"]
> [SetUp "1"] 1... Nd1 2. Bab1 Nc3 3. Bbc2! Ne4 4. Bb1! Nf6 5. Bhf5! Ng4 6. Bhg1! Nf2 7. Bhg2! Nh3 8. Bh2! Ng5 9. Bd7! Nf3 10. Bg3! Ne5 11. Bc8 Nf7 12. Bhb2! Nd6 13. Bch3! Nb5 14. Bg1 Na3 15. Ba2 Nc2 16. Bh8 Nxa1
>
> #### Other variations
>
> The following lines show the optimal lion strategy to reach a win in five moves. The starting position is after **1... Nd1**. Reviewing with a PGN viewer is recommended since there are many subvariations, and many of those deeply nested lines.
>
> **Bab8**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bab8 Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhf3?? Ng4 4. Bg1! (4. Bhg3? Nf6) 4... Nf6 5. Bf5! (5. Bc2? Nd7) 5... Nd5 6. Bh7! Nc3) (3. Bhc6?? Ng4 4. Bg1! Nf6) 3... Ng4 4. Bg1! (4. Bhg3?? Nf6 5. Bc2 *{or Bf5}* Nd7 6. Ba7! Nb6) 4... Nf6 5. Bhb1! (5. Bc2? *{or Bd3?}* Nd7 6. Bba7! Ne5 7. Bh7! Nc6 8. Bac5 (8. Bab6 Nb4 9. Bab1 *{or Bb3}* Nc2) 8... Nb4 9. Bab1 *{or Bb3/Bag8}* Nc2) (5. Bg6? Nd7 6. Bba7! Ne5 7. Bh7! (7. Be8? Nc6) 7... Nc6 8. Bac5 (8. Bab6 Nb4 9. Bab1 *{or Bb3}* Nc2) 8... Nb4 9. Bab1 *{or Bb3/Bag8}* Nc2) (5. Bf5?? Nd7 6. Bba7! Nb6) 5... Nd5 6. Bh7! (6. Bb3?? Nb6) 6... Nb6 7. Bab7! (7. Bac6?? Nd7 8. Bba7! Nf6) 7... Nd7 8. Bba7! (8. Bd6?? Nf6) 8... Nf8 9. Bhg8! (9. Bc2? Ng6 10. Bhg7! Nf4) 9... Ng6 10. Bhg7! (10. Bhf6? Nf4) 10... Ne7 11. Bh7! Nc6
>
> **Bab1**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bab1 Nc3 3. Bbc2! (3. Bbg6?? Ne4 4. Bg8! Ng3 5. Bhf3! Nf5 6. Bgh5! Ne3 7. Ba2! Nc2) (3. Bbd3?? Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bag1? *{or Be3?}* Nd4) (4. Bf2? *{or Bb6?}* Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Baf3! Na6 6. Ba7! Nc5) (3. Bbf5?? Ne4 4. Bc8! Nf2 5. Bhg2 *{or Bhf3}* (5. Bhc6 Ne4 6. Ba6! Ng5) 5... Ng4 6. Bhg1 (6. Bg3 Ne3) 6... Nf6) 3... Ne4 4. Bb1! (4. Bb3? Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bg6?? Nf7) 5... Nf7 6. Bhg7! (6. Bhc3? Ne5 7. Ba2! Nf3) 6... Nh6 7. Bh7! Ng4 8. Bhg1 (8. Bhb8 Nf6 9. Bb1 (9. Bg6 Nd5) 9... Ne4) 8... Nf2 9. Bhg2! Nh3) (4. Ba4?? Nd6 5. Bd1 (5. Bac2 Nf7 6. Bhf6! Ng5 7. Bg8! (7. Bhg6? Nf3) 7... Nf3 8. Bg3! Nd4) (5. Bf2 Nf7 6. Bhg7! Ng5 7. Bg8! (7. Bg6? Nf3) 7... Ne4 8. Bfg1 (8. Ba7 Ng3) 8... Nf2) (5. Bb8 Nf7 6. Bhg7! (6. Bhc3? Ne5) 6... Ng5 7. Bb1! (7. Bg8? Nf3) 7... Ne6 8. Bh8! Nc7) (5. Bb3? Nf7 6. Bhf6! Ng5 7. Bg6 *{or Bhg8}* Nf3) (5. B8c6?? *{or B4c6??}* Nf7) 5... Nc8 6. Bag1! (6. Bf2? *{or Be3?/B7d4?/Bc5?/Bab8?}* Nb6) 6... Nb6 7. Bab7! Nd7 8. Bc7! Nc5) (4. Bhg1?? Nf2 5. Bhg2! (5. Bhd5? *{or Bhb7?}* Nh3 6. Bh2! Ng5) (5. Bhc6? Nh3) 5... Nh3 6. Bgc5! (6. Bgb6? Ng5) 6... Nf4 7. Bh1! Ng6) (4. Bb7?? Ng5 5. Bg8! (5. Bhg6? Nf7) 5... Nf7 6. Bhg7! Nd6 7. Ba8! Nc8) (4. Bg8?? Nf2 5. Bhf3 (5. Bhc6 Ng4 6. Bhg1! Nf6) 5... Ng4 6. Bhg1! Nh6) (4. Bab8?? Nf2 5. Bhf3! Ng4 6. Bg1 *{or Bhg3}* Nf6) (4. Bf4?? Nf2 5. Bhb7! Ne4) (4. Bc7?? Ng3 5. Bhg2! Nf5) (4. Bhb8?? Ng5 5. Bg8! Nf7) (4. Bb6?? *{or Bg6??/Bab2??}* Nf2) 4... Nf6 5. Bhf5! (5. Bhg6? Ng4 6. Bhg1! (6. Bg3?? Nf2 7. Bhg2! Ne4) (6. Bc7?? Ne5 7. Bh5 (7. Bh7 Nf7) 7... Ng6) 6... Nf2 7. Bhf3! (7. Bhc6? Ne4 8. Bh5 (8. Bc2 Nd2 9. Bh1! Nb3) (8. Bh7? *{or Ba2?}* Nc3) 8... Nd2 9. Ba2! Nb3) (7. Bhb7? Nh3 8. Bh2! Nf4 9. Bh7! Ng6) 7... Ne4 8. Bh1! (8. Bc2? Nd2 9. Bh1! Nb3) (8. Ba2? Nc3) 8... Ng3 9. Bhf3! Ne2 10. Bgf2 *{or Bh2}* Nc3) (5. Bhc2?? Ne4 6. Ba2! Nf2) 5... Ng4 6. Bhg1! (6. Bhb8? Ne5 7. Bg1! (7. Bf2? Nd7 8. Bh2 (8. Bba7 *{or Bc7}* Nb6) 8... Ne5) 7... Nf3 8. Bb6! Nd2 9. Ba2! Nb3) (6. Bg3?? Nf2 7. Bhg2! Ne4) (6. Bf4?? Ne5 7. Bg3! Ng6) 6... Nf2 7. Bhg2! (7. Bhf3?? Nh3 8. Bh2! Ng1) (7. Bhd5?? Nd1 8. Bg8! Nc3) (7. Bhc6?? Ne4 8. Bh3 *{or Bh7}* Nc3) 7... Nh3 8. Bh2! (8. Bgc5? Nf4 9. Bh1! Ne2) (8. Bge3?? Ng5) 8... Ng5 9. Bd7! (9. Bc8? Nf7 10. Bhf6 *{or Bhg7}* Nd6) (9. Bg3? Ne4) (9. Bhb8? Nf7) 9... Nf3 10. Bg3! Ne5 11. Bc8 *{or Be8}* Nf7
>
> **Bag1?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bag1? Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhc6?? Ng4 4. Bb8! Nf6) 3... Nh3 4. Ba7! (4. Bc5? Ng5 5. Bhg8! Nf3 6. Bg3! Nd4 7. Ba7! Nc6) (4. Bb6?? Ng5 5. Bhb1 (5. Bhg8 Nf7 6. Bhg7! Nh6) 5... Nf3 6. Bg3 (6. Bb8 Ne5) 6... Ne1) 4... Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bhb1? Nf3 6. Bg3! Nh4 7. Bf1 *{or Bh1}* Ng6 8. Bhg7! Nf4) 5... Nf3 6. Bg3 (6. Bc7 Nd4 7. Bh2! (7. Bg3? Nc6) 7... Nc6 8. Bc5 *{or Bb6}* Nb4 9. Bb1 *{or Bab3}* Nc2) 6... Nh4 7. Bh1! (7. Bf1? Ng6 8. Bhc3 *{or Bhf6}* Ne7) (7. Bh3? *{or Bge4?}* Ng6) 7... Ng6 8. Bhc3 (8. Bhf6 Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc8) 8... Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc6
>
> **Bhg1?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bhg1? Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhd5?? Ne4 4. Bdc4! (4. Bdc6? Nf6) 4... Ng5 5. Bhg8! Nf3 6. Bgf2! Nd2) (3. Bhc6?? Ne4 4. Bb1 *{or Bg6/Bhg7/Bhg8}* (4. Bb8 *{or Bh2}* Nf6) 4... Nc3) (3. Bhb7?? Ne4 4. Bc6 *{or Bc8}* Nf6) 3... Nh3 4. Bh2! (4. Bgb6? Ng5 5. Bhg8! Nf7 6. Bhg7! (6. Bhf6? Nh6) 6... Nh6 7. Bh7! Nf5) (4. Bge3?? Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bhb1? Ne4) 5... Nf7 6. Bhc3! Nh6) (4. Bgd4?? Ng5 5. Bhg8! Nf7) (4. Bgc5?? Nf4 5. Bf1 *{or Bh1}* Ng6) 4... Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bhb1? Nf3 6. Bg3! Nh4 7. Bf1 *{or Bh1}* Ng6 8. Bhg7! Nf4) 5... Nf3 6. Bg3 (6. Bc7 Nd4 7. Bh2! (7. Bg3? Nc6) 7... Nc6 8. Bc5 *{or Bb6}* Nb4 9. Bb1 *{or Bab3}* Nc2) 6... Nh4 7. Bh1! (7. Bf1? Ng6 8. Bhc3 *{or Bhf6}* Ne7) (7. Bh3? *{or Bge4?}* Ng6) 7... Ng6 8. Bhc3 (8. Bhf6 Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc8) 8... Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc6
>
> **Bab7?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bab7? Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhf3? Ng4 4. Bhg1! (4. Bg3?? Nf6) 4... Nf6 5. Bg6! (5. Bc2? Nd5 6. Bh7! Nc3) 5... Ne4 6. Bh1! (6. Bgh5? *{or Ba8?}* Nc3) (6. Ba6? Nd2) 6... Ng3 7. Bhf3! Ne2 8. Bh2! Nc1) (3. Bhc6?? Ne4 4. Ba8! Nf6) 3... Ng4 4. Bhg1! (4. Bg3?? Nf6) 4... Ne3 5. Bh1! (5. Bh3?? Nc2 6. Baf6! Na3) (5. Bgf3?? *{or Bge4??}* Nc2) 5... Nc2 6. Bac3! (6. Bab2? Nb4 7. Bab1 *{or Bag8}* Nc6) (6. Baf6? Nb4 7. Bab1! Nc6) 6... Nb4 7. Bab1! Nc6 8. Bab6! Na5 9. Ba6 *{or Ba8}* Nc4
>
> **Bhg8?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bhg8? Nc3 3. Bac4! (3. Bab3? Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bf2?? Nd4 5. Ba2 *{or Ba4}* Nc2) (4. Bb6?? Nc7 5. Bab7! Nd5) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! (5. Bag2? Nd5 6. Bf7! Nf4 7. Ba8! Ng6) (5. Baf3? Nd5 6. Bf7 (6. Ba4 Ne7 7. Bh7! Ng6) (6. Ba2? *{or Bh7?}* Nf6) 6... Ne7 7. Ba8! Ng6) 5... Nd5 6. Ba8! (6. Bf7? Ne7 7. Ba8! Ng6) (6. Bh7? Nf6) 6... Nb6 7. Bac6! Nd7 8. Ba7 *{or Bbc7}* Nf6) (3. Baf7?? Nd5 4. Bh7! Nc7) 3... Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bag1? Nd4 5. Bb8! (5. Bc7? Ne2 6. Bf2 *{or Bgh2}* (6. Ba7 Nd4) 6... Ng3) 5... Nc6 6. Bg3! Ne7 7. Bh7! Ng6) (4. Bc5?? Nd4 5. Bb6! Nc2) (4. Bb6?? Nc7 5. Bab7! Nd5) 4... Nc7 5. Bab7! (5. Baf3?? Nd5 6. Ba2 *{or Ba6}* Nf6) (5. Bae4?? Nd5 6. Bb1! Nf6) (5. Bac6?? Nd5 6. B6b5! Nf6) 5... Na6 6. Ba7! (6. Bbf4? Nc5 7. Ba8! Nb3) (6. Bbd6?? Nb4) 6... Nb4 7. Be2! (7. Bf1? Nc2 8. Bab2 *{or Bac3}* Ne3) (7. Bag1? *{or Bb6?}* Nc2) 7... Nc6 8. Bb6! Nd4 9. Bd1 *{or Bf1}* Nc2
>
> **Bb3?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bb3? Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhf3? Ng4 4. Bhg1! Nf6 5. Bg6! (5. Bd3? Ne4 6. Bg8! Ng5) 5... Ne4 6. Bg8! (6. Bc2? Nd2 7. Bh1! Nb3) (6. Bfd1? *{or Ba2?}* Nc3) (6. Bh1? *{or Be2?/Bfh5?}* Ng3) 6... Nd6 7. Bb1! (7. Bgh5? Nc8) 7... Nc8 8. Bb8! Nb6) (3. Bhc6?? Ng4 4. Bhg1 *{or Bg3}* Nf6) (3. Bhb7?? Ng4 4. Bhg1! Nf6) 3... Ne4 4. Bh1 (4. Ba2 Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bhb1? Nf3 6. Bg3! Nh4 7. Bf1 *{or Bh1}* Ng6 8. Bhg7! Nf4) 5... Nf3 6. Bg3 (6. Bc7 Nd4 7. Bh2! (7. Bg3? Nc6) 7... Nc6 8. Bc5 *{or Bb6}* Nb4 9. Bb1 *{or Bab3}* Nc2) 6... Nh4 7. Bh1! (7. Bf1? Ng6 8. Bhc3 *{or Bhf6}* Ne7) (7. Bh3? *{or Bge4?}* Ng6) 7... Ng6 8. Bhc3 (8. Bhf6 Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc8) 8... Ne7 9. Bh7! Nc6) (4. Bhg1? Ng5 5. Bhg8! Nf3 6. Bgf2! Nd4 7. Ba2 *{or Ba4}* Nc2) (4. Bhg8? Nf6 5. Bgf7! Ng4 6. Bhg1 (6. Bg3 Ne5 7. Be8 *{or Bg8}* Nc6) 6... Ne3 7. Bh1! Nc2) (4. Bab8? Nf6 5. Bg6! (5. Bb1? Nd7 6. Ba7 *{or Bbc7}* Nb6) 5... Nd7 6. Ba7! Nb6 7. Bab7! Nc8) (4. Ba4?? Ng5 5. Bb1 (5. Bg8 Nf3 6. Bg3 *{or Bc7}* Nh4) 5... Nf3 6. Bg3! Nd4) (4. Bf4?? Nf6 5. Bb1! Nd5) (4. Bhb8?? Ng5 5. Bb1 (5. Bhg8 Nf7) 5... Nf3) (4. Bab2?? Nf6 5. Bg6! Ng4) (4. Bb6?? *{or Bc7??}* Nf6) 4... Ng5 5. Bhg8! (5. Bg6?? Nf7) 5... Nf7 6. Bhg7! (6. Bhc3? Ne5 7. Ba2! Nf3) 6... Nh6 7. Bh7! Ng4 8. Bhg1 (8. Bhb8 Nf6 9. Bb1 (9. Bg6 Nd5) 9... Ne4) 8... Nf2 9. Bhg2! Nh3
>
> **Bhg2?**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bhg2? Nc3 3. Bag8! (3. Bb3? Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bb6?? Nd4 5. Ba2! Nc2) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! (5. Baf3? Nd5 6. Bh1 (6. Ba4 Nc3) (6. Bh3 Ne3) 6... Nf6) 5... Nd5 6. Ba8! (6. Bh1? *{or Bba4?}* Nf6) (6. Bh3? Ne3) 6... Nb6 7. Bac6! Nd7 8. Ba7! Nf6) (3. Bc4? Nb5 4. Bab8! Nc7 5. Bab7! Na6 6. Ba7! (6. Bbd6? Nb4) 6... Nb4 7. Be2! Nc2 8. Bab2! Ne3) (3. Bf7?? Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bf2? *{or Bb6?}* Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! Ne6 6. Bfe8! Nd4) 3... Nd5 4. Bb1! (4. Bf7?? Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Bab7! (5. Bac6?? Nb5 6. Bab8! Na3) 5... Nb5 6. Bab8! (6. Bc5?? Nc3) 6... Na3 7. Bba2! (7. Bg6? Nc2 8. Bab2! Ne3) 7... Nc2 8. Bab2! (8. Bac3? Ne3) 8... Nb4 9. Bb1! Nc6
>
> **Bhb8??, Bg3??**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bhb8?? (2. Bg3?? Nc3 3. Bb3! (3. Bc4?? Ne4 4. Be1 *{or Bh4}* (4. Bh2 Nf2) 4... Ng3) 3... Nb5 4. Bab8! (4. Bb6? Nc7 5. Bac6! Nd5 6. Ba7 (6. Bd8 Nc3) 6... Nf6) (4. Baf2?? Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! Na6 6. Ba7! Nc5 7. Ba2! Ne4 8. Bh2! Nf2) 2... Nc3 3. Bb3! (3. Bf7? Nb5 4. Bg1! (4. Bf2? Nc7 5. Bac6! Na6 6. Bba7! Nc5) (4. Be3?? *{or Bb6??}* Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! Ne6 6. Bfe8! Nc5 7. Bb1! Nb3) (3. Bc4?? Nd5 4. Bf1 (4. Be2 Nf6 5. Bc2 *{or Bhd3/Bg6}* Ne4) (4. Bb3? Nb6) 4... Ne3 5. Bh3! Nc2) (3. Bag8?? Nd5 4. Bf7! Nb6) 3... Nb5 4. Bg1! (4. Bf2?? *{or Bb6??}* Nc7) 4... Nc7 5. Bac6! (5. Baf3? Nd5 6. Bfd1 (6. Ba2 *{or Ba4}* Nc3) (6. Bbc2 *{or Bba7/Bgh2/Bab2}* Nf6) (6. Be2 Nf4) 6... Ne3) 5... Nd5 6. Bba7 (6. Ba8 Nb6 7. Baf3 (7. Bac6 Nd7 8. Bba7! Nf8) 7... Nd7 8. Bba7! Nf6) (6. Bd1? *{or Bb5?/Bf2?/Bgh2?/Bab2?}* Nf6) 6... Nf6 7. Bb1 (7. Bg6 Ne4 8. Ba8 *{or Bce8}* Ng3) 7... Ne4 8. Bg8! Ng3
>
> **Bg6??, Be6??**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bg6?? (2. Be6?? Nf2 3. Bhg2! Ng4 4. Bhg1! Ne5 5. Ba2 (5. Bb3 Nc6 6. Bab6! Nd4 7. Ba2! Nc2) (5. Bc8? Nc6) (5. Beg8? Ng6) 5... Nc6 6. Bac5 (6. Bab6 Nb4 7. Bab1 *{or Bb3}* Nc2) 6... Nb4 7. Bab1 *{or Bb3/Bag8}* Nc2) 2... Nf2 3. Bhg2! (3. Bhb7? Ne4 4. Bc8! (4. Bc6? Nc3) 4... Nc3 5. Bb3! Nb5) 3... Ng4 4. Bhg1! (4. Bg3? Ne5 5. Bh7 (5. Be8 Nc6) 5... Ng6) (4. Bc7? Ne5 5. Bh7! Ng6) 4... Ne3 5. Bh1! (5. Bh3? *{or B2e4?}* Nc2) 5... Nc2 6. Bac3! Nb4 7. Bab1! Nc6
>
> **Bf7??, Bc5??, Bf5??**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bf7?? (2. Bc5?? Nf2 3. Bhg2! Ng4 4. Bhg1! Nf6 5. Bc2 *{or Bf5}* Nd5) (2. Bf5?? Nf2 3. Bhf3! Ng4 4. Bhg1! (4. Bg3? Nh2) 4... Ne3 5. Bh3 *{or Bh7}* Nc2)2... Nf2 3. Bhg2! Ng4 4. Bhg1! (4. Bg3? Ne5 5. Ba2 (5. Bb3 Nc6) 5... Ng6) (4. Bc7? Ne5 5. Ba2 *{or Bb3}* Ng6) 4... Ne5 5. Ba2 (5. Bb3 Nc6 6. Bab6! Nd4 7. Ba2! Nc2) (5. Be8? *{or Bfg8?}* Ng6) 5... Nc6 6. Bac5 (6. Bab6 Nb4 7. Bab1 *{or Bb3}* Nc2) 6... Nb4 7. Bab1 *{or Bb3/Bag8}* Nc2
>
> **The rest**
>
> [FEN "B6B/B6B/8/8/8/8/B6B/B2n3B w - - 0 2"]
> [SetUp "1"] 2. Bb6?? (2. Baf3?? *{or Bhf3??}* Nc3) (2. Bc2?? *{or B7d4??/Bac6??/Bc4??}* Nf2) (2. Bag7?? Nf2 3. Bhg2! Ng4) (2. Bhc6?? Nc3 3. Bc4! Nb5 4. Bab8! Nc7) (2. B2e5?? Nc3 3. Bb3! Nb5 4. Bf2! Nd4) (2. Bf4?? Nc3 3. Bb3! Nb5 4. Bf2 *{or Bab8}* Nc7) (2. Bhg7?? Nc3 3. Bb3 *{or Bc4}* Nb5 4. Bb6 *{or Bab8}* Nc7) 2... Nf2 3. Bhf3! Ng4 4. Bhg1 *{or Bg3}* Nf6
>
> #### Conclusion
>
> The preceding variations demonstrate the tactics adopted by the lion versus various zebra defenses. It's not possible to present the full analysis, but the final result is the lion always wins.

## Partial answer

*Note*: This was the first cut at the game analysis prior to the full analysis done above.

If we limit the zebras to execute the four-corners strategy suggested in other answers, the problem is more manageable. An analyzing every state where the zebras restrict themselves to the four squares in each corner shows that this strategy is unsustainable. Sooner or later, the zebras have to abandon those squares.

To demonstrate this, I implemented a Python program to with an optimal lion. (It should work in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x, but let me know if it not.) The user takes the role of the zebras. To reduce the state space, I limited the zebras to having four on white and four on black with two zebras on each long diagonal. This is the optimal organization for the zebras when playing the four corners.

Once the program is started, you receive a command prompt.

To create an initial position, use the `start` command followed by `{l}:{z1}{z2}...{z8}` where `{l}` is the lion's square and `{zn}` is each zebra's square. For instance, to use the position shown in Prem's answer use:

```
start d5:a1a2a7a8h1h2h7h8
```

The lion will move and the next position shown. To move just enter a move for a zebra, which must be to one of the corner squares. For example:

```
a2b1
```

The zebra move will be shown, along with the optimal reply from the lion.

To take back the last move:

```
undo
```

And to leave the program:

```
quit
```

#### Optimal Lion vs. Four-Corner Zebras Demo

```
from cmd import Cmd
from itertools import product, combinations, starmap, chain
from functools import reduce
from zlib import decompress
from base64 import b64decode
import sys
import re

LMOVES_COMPRESSED = [
    'eJztkMEKwDAIQ0/B///jla2dmmjPPTQD6RTDi2ZXV4cI+otXYTrr6I0PvEsO5Ad/TV90slh9IfUD'
    'W8Es5ImSpkg12nl/c6kQkUgl13c74xy5r7mM/IRiLdTT5dBQFyl+IGFi8iZjk35/NDwguyEr',
    'eJzNktsOgCAMQ0OWpv//x+puDEUfF0vAMWqyMxijT9KoRqwh/CyFPmIXK8t/xYOICRYfTc1ca4V7'
    'Li65nUdeHN4LnKOTC0xhfgBfTZqFH2KeWvxUzRdHP5e+msJFrS1LSnTBbMKdvRD9hEt05nsqMfye'
    'bJ/OjSe4rv4EnXDh5QHHmA45',
    'eJzdk1EKwDAIQykSdv8br5Zt1mGq3ef8CuMlmsJa0znGtL9p3Bp9Lt2VfZ8ZouG8cabjiXcYjEfA'
    'wO96tIDs8pmM2dS013Qb3RXe772ko07QV7XkTO4l7/zmI0ZTMkYg8Z2LXpXuWZfK/bxXnuN6we6s'
    'eb9rls/+F2wyLP8ESRYaZQ==',
    'eJylU1sKwDAIQ0rvf+VRRBpfqTA/irg0JtOKiKwl5NTMIuf/MVbRjnirxvBA/ayXIfjpXXD9sb43'
    '4+k8IlIZsvJeVf7K/8O0MvHe4Tn/cel9zuaF2xJvzL3PZnr0dRMxD3U96omv4L2HyNxtFGK6Paz0'
    '1PiXrzsvr7/OsWPOs6rYyW8Hf/+dl8hShWI+eSgNYQ==',
    'eJztU9sOxSAIezC0///H41JwZtn7yckaB1pRRixr/T0ILBS4DBvULmBMF6YIn9cuc+pjgDFE7ZoH'
    'msXXQJhar9rNvBEUq5znOh3ECMyTfm2kCO9hk71Kmgqs/lq0+KqFHZR3BnHj8++hC/kCewW3rQzK'
    'o1NdL4bvI+EfWR7Uh5+HWitawM2KV/ZnRCnCtvBCE1KbtMfjuTvmoLjFf4vZwtt+zh7inF7rZjxi'
    'KBXmsE4oXLETHMk=',
    'eJy1UkkOxCAMa4Qc///HkwVoeiodgQ+RD5YdB67rHbIJC1FL2JUlQpA2xaeKOif7BBTKoENDdZIa'
    'psbAbb3Cs2WiZesjdz1LAMHsApktzGc25d10pBzrFW4o/vFE9Ft+6dUc/T6gTt7sUg6/WGrQNe48'
    'NPt7jX1s+A7OW/Dc4d9ec9sWjYC719CwaE728onkbJ+z0oHl3Z87Ry/eON0L5R+i+Nf5A3ZIC6U=',
    'eJyVVNESxDAEZHac///jSyRKEu31PHSMWcsiJQr7mGV/GE8TFpkRCNyfESIArKIXJvnDMC1yxazA'
    'pFwUPJ0h597z9E9kuZ9VLDyHrlG95a796NmPfSd/Q5Q8knVh1zVbeTXDrAu1LoSutrtyhlmLNk9v'
    'dDm/dbfzmC7ETqt9idV6wND7O+wXxK40/BkhYlbuXTmGdkxU8njzbjCy1MKCGevKsz3n/Ieu/r6u'
    'Wns/pkvsHhyjta6c21Kk1KURx1Fr7Ivz/SDevmPg711zpJjP4z2PS/j137BnkeJ6wyOPmMFjOMmR'
    'jPkC9XEYPw==',
    'eJzdk8EKwDAIQ+tMzP//8XSFbbAdS6F9hyC5PdTW5nEMgm8CBn2ZqDXayz0kxpOeDdf3YjlQPdVn'
    'buDlbpabQgA9/WqW9xLSwuq/UHMmsYPXfYt/nFyICAc=',
    'eJzdU0EOwzAIgwDz/388EpVANKp113GykDEYEqIZrxX0R1hWXHlTUw1sGx8cApElBm44X3pZ4Zij'
    'Q4ezds8zsTU6Aola15R+Hi06iU/Og/088LVGLhwEZ2LuOJqcoiNSdot+z2PFJz72MwZw7c0Mo9OZ'
    'KPJsvsNOx/Nxl6VzYV6xa8cIrB7czQPevTjxr77mxFtHFa0vFI6ooJlHxIu3F9fpfAGi6QudL+ek'
    'rzLb0cv/V9zCxa2bx98wynu+87XfAxOsv2nm/V6tDpf/wne9Di+J3xBnFgw=',
    'eJzdktuSxCAIROWSzv//8WqDDsbJy9Y+LZliLHMEm47q/wy7esBEXGEuDmblToPdPZBMD75V5dp6'
    'FrcHAzKaDLjzYMCftNbGAnHkwQhvEhkAJnkyeef7In8tRnq86/IeY83rpZa21sr7O0lJvaO/yaZr'
    'dRfOITc11tTFx1vUGd0bVatuukYdRB12YfeYkmobHXnKbTBL+110Ua9fh1/Loze/ogsmAyp9Mqnd'
    'lwtfPI23xS/+/cavYLzMFrtfmFqw6+rzMc7Q5p0lGawcM4w5x5O6ok74VZnjO7TDr3nu42bttbR7'
    '8ctnzS9+HXlnUBS9MX9Zp36lhfkBhUATYg==',
    ]

VALID_SQUARES = tuple(product(range(8), repeat=2))

ZSQUARE_GROUPS = (((0,0),(1,1),(6,6),(7,7)), ((0,1),(1,0),(6,7),(7,6)),
                  ((0,7),(1,6),(6,1),(7,0)), ((0,6),(1,7),(6,0),(7,1)))

ALL_CORNERS = reduce(frozenset.union, ZSQUARE_GROUPS, frozenset())

def comb2(iterable): return combinations(iterable, 2)
Z_STATES = list(map(frozenset, starmap(chain, product(*map(comb2, ZSQUARE_GROUPS)))))

LNORM_POS = ((0,0),(2,0),(4,0),(6,0),(1,1),(3,1),(5,1),(2,2),(4,2),(3,3))

pos_combos = [[i in c for i in range(4)] for c in combinations(range(4), 2)]

LMOVE_DELTAS = ((-2,-1),(-2,1),(-1,-2),(-1,2),(1,-2),(1,2),(2,-1),(2,1))

def map_lmoves(l_pos, move_data):
    return (l_pos, dict(zip(Z_STATES, bytearray(decompress(b64decode(move_data))))))

LMOVE_LU = dict(map(map_lmoves, LNORM_POS, LMOVES_COMPRESSED))

def str2id(s): return (ord(s[0])-ord('a'), ord(s[1])-ord('1'))
def id2str(id): return chr(ord('a')+id[0])+chr(ord('1')+id[1])
def move2str(move): return "%s%s" % (id2str(move[0]), id2str(move[1]))
def str2move(s): return (str2id(s[:2]), str2id(s[2:]))
def refl_a1h8(id): return (id[1],id[0])
def refl_a8h1(id): return (7-id[1],7-id[0])
def refl_lr(id): return (7-id[0],id[1])

def get_l_move(l_sq, z_sqs):
    norm_fs = []
    if l_sq[1]>7-l_sq[0]:   norm_fs.append(refl_a8h1)
    if l_sq[1]>l_sq[0]:     norm_fs.append(refl_a1h8)
    if 1&(l_sq[0]^l_sq[1]): norm_fs.append(refl_lr)

    l_norm_sq, z_norm_sqs = l_sq, z_sqs
    for f in norm_fs:
        l_norm_sq, z_norm_sqs = f(l_norm_sq), map(f, z_norm_sqs)
    d_f, d_r = LMOVE_DELTAS[LMOVE_LU[l_norm_sq][frozenset(z_norm_sqs)]]
    l_next_sq = (l_norm_sq[0]+d_f, l_norm_sq[1]+d_r)
    for f in norm_fs[::-1]: l_next_sq = f(l_next_sq)
    return l_next_sq

def get_z_cands(l_sq, z_sqs):
    cands = []
    for z_sq in z_sqs:
        for d_f, d_r in product((-1,1), repeat=2):
            z_next = (z_sq[0]+d_f, z_sq[1]+d_r)
            while z_next in VALID_SQUARES:
                if  z_next == l_sq or z_next in z_sqs:
                    break
                if z_next in ALL_CORNERS:
                    cands.append((z_sq, z_next))
                z_next = (z_next[0]+d_f, z_next[1]+d_r)
    return cands

def print_board(l_sq, z_sqs):
    def square_c(i, j): return ' Lz'[(i,j)==l_sq or ((i,j) in z_sqs and 2)]
    sys.stdout.write('+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n')
    for r in range(7,-1,-1):
        line = '|%s| %d' % ('|'.join([square_c(f,r) for f in range(8)]), r+1)
        sys.stdout.write('%s\n+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n' % line)
    sys.stdout.write(' a b c d e f g h\n')

class ZLCmd(Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.phases = []

    def init_game(self, sstr):
        match = re.match(r"([a-h][1-8]):(([abgh][1278]){8})$", sstr)
        if match is None:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid position definition string')
        l_str, z_str, _ = match.groups()
        l_sq = str2id(l_str)
        z_sqs = frozenset(str2id(z_str[2*i:2*i+2]) for i in range(8))
        if l_sq in z_sqs:
            raise RuntimeError('Lion position overlaps zebras')
        if not all([2==len(z_sqs.intersection(group)) for group in ZSQUARE_GROUPS]):
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid zebra positions')

        self.phases = []
        self.l_move(None, l_sq, z_sqs)

    def print_last_phase(self):
        if len(self.phases) > 0:
            phase = self.phases[-1]
            l0, l1 = phase['l_move']
            z_sqs = phase['z_sqs']
            print_board(l0, z_sqs)
            sys.stdout.write('\nL move: %s\n\n' % move2str((l0,l1)))
            print_board(l1, z_sqs)
            if len(phase['z_cands']) == 0:
                sys.stdout.write('\nGame over\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('**No active game**\n')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

    def l_move(self, z_move, l_sq, z_sqs):
        l_next_sq = get_l_move(l_sq, z_sqs)
        if l_next_sq in z_sqs:
            # z_sqs = z_sqs.difference((l_next_sq,))
            z_cands = []
        else:
            z_cands = get_z_cands(l_next_sq, z_sqs)

        z_cands = dict((move2str(z_cand), z_cand) for z_cand in z_cands)

        self.phases.append({'z_move': z_move, 'z_sqs': z_sqs,
                            'l_move': (l_sq, l_next_sq), 'z_cands': z_cands})

        self.print_last_phase()

    def z_move(self, move):
        phase = self.phases[-1]
        l_sq, z_sqs = phase['l_move'][1], phase['z_sqs']
        self.l_move(move, l_sq, z_sqs.symmetric_difference(move))

    def do_quit(self, line):
        """Quit the program."""
        return True

    def do_undo(self, line):
        """Undo last move."""
        if len(self.phases) > 1:
            self.phases.pop()
            self.print_last_phase()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('Cannot undo\n')

    def do_start(self, line):
        """Start at a new position.

        Example: start b1:a1a2a7a8h1h2h7h8
        """
        try:
            if len(line.split()) != 1:
                raise RuntimeError('Invalid number of arguments')
            self.init_game(line)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            sys.stdout.write('Error: %s\n' % str(e))

    def default(self, line):
        if re.match(r"([abcdefgh][12345678]){2}$", line):
            if len(self.phases) > 0 and line in self.phases[-1]['z_cands']:
                self.z_move(self.phases[-1]['z_cands'][line])
            else:
                sys.stdout.write('Error: Invalid move, %s\n' % line)
        else:
            Cmd.default(self, line)

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        ZLCmd().cmdloop()
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write('Fatal error: %s\n' % str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you call optimal (how does the lion react)? Going through code is hard and evrybody is not a master in Python. Thanks for the script however!

Comment: @Untitpoi By optimal I mean that the lion always plays moves that lead him closer to the capturing a zebra. The bulk of the code is a compressed table that just holds the lion's optimal move for each state. It wasn't really intended to be read, but just to allow people to play the four-corner defense against an optimal lion and show that that strategy does not hold. In a comment on the OP, justhalf asked if someone could analyze the answers given, so that's what this partial answer is.

Comment: So, after 3 years the problem seems to be finally solved.

Comment: @UserNotFound I tried for some time to find a way to present a complete proof, but failed. It's fascinating how nuanced the game is. Maybe I'll endeavor a little more to reduce the full state space into something that will fit in an answer.

Comment: Is there any simple way to show that the lion wins in all other combinations of light/dark-square zebras?  The lion's victory stems from its ability to find ways of moving twice for each light-square zebra move. If there were fewer dark-square zebras, it might not be able to find all the opportunities it might need.  I'd guess that the lion would gain more advantage by having extra light-square targets than it would lose by having fewer dark-square ones, but can that be easily proven?

Comment: @supercat I might be possible to show for configurations of 8-0, 7-1, or 6-2. The lion wins in 6, 7, and 8 moves respectively. For 5-3, which has even more states than 4-4, it takes 11 moves. If I get some time, I'll take a look and see if there is a simple demonstration for any or all of those.

Comment: @DKrueger: How about for 7-0, 6-0, or 4-3?  I think 3-3 would easily be able to escape indefinitely because all four of the just-off-corner light squares would have one Zebra, and all such dark squares by another, thus avoiding the possibility of zebras getting in each others' ways, but I don't know about the other possibilities I mentioned.

Comment: @supercat I only analyzed eight zebras because that's what the rules in the OP stated. I have a feeling, though, that 4-3 might be advantageous enough to favor the zebras.

Answer (score 6):

Place 4 Zebras on White, and 4 Zebras on Black.
At any move, Lion can attack only Black or only White, so only 4 pieces.

Keep the 4 Black Zebras in the 4 corners, or adjacent to the corners.
Keep the 4 White Zebras in the 4 corners, or adjacent to the corners.
Now, only one Zebra can be in danger at any move. So only move that Zebra to the **opposite corner**.

**Conclusion : Zebras can always escape.**

In the figure , the blue lines are two possible ways to attack the left top corner Zebras, but the gray lines are the responses to escape. Same applies for all other corners.

**Escape Algorithm Overview :**
The Lion can be in only one of the 4 big quadrants (left bottom, left top, right bottom, right top) and so it can attack only one of the two Zebras in that quadrant. That Zebra has to move to the **opposite corner**.
If the Lion also moves to that opposite quadrant, then that Zebra must go back to initial position.
If the Lion moves to any other quadrant, then one Zebra from that quadrant will so move to opposite quadrant.
If a piece may come into danger by moving, then simply move a Zebra of the other colour.

Definition of **opposite corner** :
For the Zebras, there are **8** corners formed by left/right or top/bottom or inner/outer.
For getting opposite, all 3 Dimensions must change: left must become right and vice-versa , top must become bottom and vice-versa , inner must become outer and vice-versa. Example : top-left-outer corner is opposite of bottom-right-inner corner.

**Aim of every move is** Either **(1)** If a piece is in danger, move that piece to opposite corner Or **(2)** If no piece is in danger, **(2A)** Move a piece back to original position, provided it is a safe move and the Lion is not blocking the way Or **(2B)** Move a piece of the opposite colour, so that no piece comes into danger by that move Or **(2C)** Move a Zebra of the same colour and the same quadrant as the Zebra blocked by the Lion in case **(2A)**.

**Explanation of (2C)** : When Lion moves from D5 to C3, one Zebra moves from A2 to G8. Now if Lion moves back to D5, Zebra can not use condition **(2A)** to go back to original position A2, because L is blocking the way. So we have to use condition **(2C)** to move one Zebra from H7 to B1. Still we are maintaining 2 Zebras of opposite colour in each quadrant.

[image: Position + Moves]

Special thanks to @Wouter & @Taemyr & @JonTheMon & @JS1 for useful comments , which improved this answer.

Comment: can you visualize this? I would appreciate that :)

Comment: @Wouter , Done.

Comment: When you move the zebra to the other corner you have two zebras on that color in that corner.  Can you guarantee that it will be safely able to get back to the original corner?

Comment: @Taemyr , Well, the Lion will take many moves to come to that corner, so in the meantime the Zebras have to come back to the initial positions.

Comment: @Prem.  He makes moves, but can you guarante that those moves does not threathen any Zebras?

Comment: What does the zebra do if after C6 the Lion goes to D4? Or does the lion at H2 move to the UL corner?

Comment: @Taemyr, the Zebra are quite far from the Lion, so yes they are gauranteed to be safe. Only when the Lion nears a corner, one Zebra has to move to the other corner.

Comment: @Pram I hear you claiming that.  But I can make the Lion move from one corner to the next while continously threathening Zebras.  (This is insufficient for a Lion win, the seqence I have found forces the Zebras back to original spaces.  But it shows that your proof is missing the most imporant step)

Comment: @JonTheMon , at all moments, only 4 Zebras "may be" in potenial danger if they move, the other 4 are not in danger. So when no Zebra is in danger, and moving some Zebras may put them in Danger, we should not move those Zebras. We only have to move the other set of 4 Zebras.

Comment: @Taemyr , I get what you are saying. I was responding thinking that you feel my answer or algorithm is wrong. Now you see you only want more clarification. My answer gives the basic overview. Ok I will soon edit my answer to include all cases.

Comment: Ok, after lion goes D5, C3, D5, what do the zebras do? Does the zebra at H7 go down, to give a pseudo-starting position?

Comment: @JonTheMon , For Lion move from D5 to C3 , Zebra A2 escapes to G7. When Lion goes back to D5 , same Zebra G7 goes back to A2 [ This is condition (2A) in my algorithm , when no piece is in danger, given in the section "Aim of every move" ]

Comment: @Prem The zebra at G8 (originally at A2) is blocked by the lion at D5

Comment: Oh nice catch @JonTheMon !! Yes , your tip is correct , we have to move to pseudo-starting position !! I will add condition (2C) to my answer.

Comment: Not sure if I have a win for the lion, but I can break your formation.  L(D5-F6)-z(H7-B1)-L(F6-G4)-z(H2-B8)-L(G4-F2)-z(H1-B7)-L(F2-E4)-z(A2-G8) Or fork at C3-L(E4-C3)-z(B1-H7)-L(C3-D5)-Zebra needs to move B7 at this point or A8 is trapped.

Comment: This is a win for the lion.  B7 only has three spots to move to.  C6 is deafeated by the lion moving B4-C6 forking A7 and B8.  A6 and C8 is defeated by respectivly C7 and B6.

Comment: Also there is a fork at from F6 that I completely missed.

Comment: @Prem Starting from your picture, lion moves: `C7 B5 C3 E2 G3 H1` killing the zebra on `H1` because it is trapped by the zebra at `G2`.

Comment: hmmm, as per my answer (& the answer by "Arghya Chakraborty") , "Zebras win", but Taemyr & JS1 are showing the loop holes in the algorithms. It may turn out that the correct answer is "Lion wins", unless our answers get some good tweaking. So now, I will think along those lines and see if it can be proved.

Comment: JS1 & JonTheMon & Taemyr & All , Will the slight change help my solution work ? I ensured that Zebras Do not block each other by Differentiating between inner & outer **corners**. If this works, fine, but if does not, then Do you think Lion can win in general ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try to think outside of the box (literally) and let the lion move outside the 8x8. Using the 2x2 in the corners strat for Zebras and Prem's starting board.

Let's go with: D5, C3, B5, A'6.  This brings up a fork on in the top left. That zebra will flee to the bottom right.

Lion A8. This brings up 2 moves for the zebras: G8 to A2 (plus mirror), G2 to B7 (zebras are safe next to lion).

Zebra G8 to A2, Lion C9. Zebra can't return to A8 or B7.  Lion goes D7, F6, G4, all moves that force a zebra to move. At that point, F2 catches the zebra that's stuck at H1.

How about zebra to B7.  Again lion goes D7 (zebra back to G2), F6, G4, F2 catches the zebra stuck at H1 again.